# Get ubuntu on another computer without internet

Tags: usb, software-installation

I want to get Ubuntu on my other computer that can't get internet, and since it can't get internet, can I download it on my current (this one) and load it on a USB to install it on the other computer?

Comment: Yes, you can download .iso file from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and create a live USB/CD to install.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can also burn Ubuntu onto a CD and use it to install in the computer with no internet.

If you need help on how to install Ubuntu:

[Install Ubuntu from a USB stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

[Install Ubuntu from a CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/installing-from-cd.html)

Comment: Try to ceep the two systems as similar as possible, so you can carry .deb files via usb to the machine without internet connection contact me for more information.